# shiny DT datatable encoding issue

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, shiny, dt

In [this](http://shiny.nibio.no/apps/test/) DT table, foreign (Norwegian) characters are displayed just
fine. However, when selecting words with foreign characters in the
filter box, nothing
is selected. The foreign characters in the
filter box are also not correctly displayed, although they seem to be UTF-8. It seems like the factor levels are different from the
displayed text in the table. This appears to be an encoding issue,
because the app and selection works just fine on the Win7 PC that is
used to produce the data set. As suggested in many fora, the text and
factor levels were converted to UTF-8 before R-saving the file on the
Win7 PC. Any help would be appreciated.